# Neural Network all predictions are the same in Julia using Flux.jl

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, julia, artificial-intelligence

I am currently developing a neural network in Julia using flux.jl package and have a problem with my predictions. My weights change compared to what they used to be at the start, but all my predictions in every element in the row matrix of -y hat aka predictions- are set into the same value(between 0 and 1 ex. 0.1245). No matter what i do, i cannot find the error in the code down below. It will be much appriciated if anyone would be willing to help with this, thanks in advance.

Note: train and test are splitted DataFrames

```
X_train = copy(train)

X_train = permutedims(Matrix(select!(X_train, Not(:"converted"))), (2,1));

y_train = permutedims(train[:, "converted"]);

X_test = copy(test)

X_test = permutedims(Matrix(select!(X_test, Not(:"converted"))), (2,1));

y_test = permutedims(test[:, "converted"]);

function NeuralNetwork()
    return Chain(
            Dense(19,25,relu),Dense(25,1,relu),
            Dense(1,1,σ)
            )
end

model = NeuralNetwork();

opt = Descent(0.005);

data=Flux.Data.DataLoader((X_train, y_train), batchsize=1)

loss(x, y) = sum(Flux.Losses.binarycrossentropy(model(x), y));

epochs = 3;

ps = Flux.params(model)

for i in 1:epochs    
    Flux.train!(loss, ps, data, opt)
end

model(X_test)
```

output of "model(X_test)":
1×45000 Matrix{Float32}:
0.139239  0.139239  0.139239  0.139239  …  0.139239  0.139239  0.139239

Comment: 1) You need to show what the X_test, ps variable, X_train, y_train, relu, σ variables are in your post. If possible make a MWE and with smaller data, 45000 may be a bit hefty to generate and try out.
2) I notice that your functions use global variables. The compiler can't infer types for that, so the performance will not be optimized. Try to pass them in as arguments.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by relu and σ variables, aren't they inherently defined as relu and sigmoid functions in Flux.jl library? Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: It could be many things, can you share also the data that are you trying to fit?